# System.out.println() not working for maven build

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, command-line

I have System.out.println() in two locations in my project.

```
    public class Class1{
        public static void main(String args[]){
               String a = arg[1]; 
               String b = arg[2]; 
               System.out.println("printing in class 1");
               Class2 obj = new Class2(a,b);
        }
    }
    public class Class2{
      public Class2(String a, String b){ //constructor
          System.out.println(a);
          System.out.println(b);
      }
    }
```

I need to do a maven build and create an executable jar file that I run from commandline passing the arguments.

The System.out.println() in Class1 is not working where as System.out.println() in Class2 is showing up.

I am executing using the command  `java -jar name.jar arg1 arg2`

I could not figure out why it is not working in Class1.

IDE that I am using is Eclipse.

Comment: Do you have the most updated Class files in your JAR?  Do you have an older JAR version somewhere on CLASSPATH? Add another `println` to Class2 and rebuild and run the project.

Comment: Yes, if I add any sysout in Class2 it is showing up on command line. I tested it even now.

Comment: Find all `name.jar` files and delete them. Find all `Class1.class` files and delete them.  If you are aginst deleteing - rename instead. Then build and run your project.

Comment: Yes, It worked if I removed the old files. Thank you :)